# how do you draw two yAxis chart in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I need to build a highchart with 2 yAxis, one on the left (primary) and one on the right(secondar). I was not able to make this work. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here or missing?

here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gsaray101/KX4AS/2/

I am using the example from the highcharts site as this:

```
yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                labels: {
                    format: '{value}ms',
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'response time',
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Secondary yAxis
                title: {
                    text: 'volume',
                    style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                },
                labels: {
                    format: '{value}',
                    style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                },
                opposite: true
            }],
```

Comment: could u give a simplified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Ishanks, http://jsfiddle.net/gsaray101/KX4AS/2/

Comment: Take a look the following demo. http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axis are 0 based.  So you need (http://jsfiddle.net/zEBSh/)

var data = [{
        "name": "1",
        "yAxis": 0,
        "data": [
            [1374019440000, 25],

```
        [1374056640000, 43],
        [1374056880000, 49]
    ]
}, {
    "name": "2",
    "yAxis":1,
    "data": [
        [1374019440000, 33],
        [1374019740000, 42],
```

Comment: thank you so much. One quick question, I would to make my lines very thin, what is the setting for that?

Comment: lineWidth
var data = [{
            "name": "1",
            "yAxis": 0,
            "lineWidth":.5,
            "data": [